# Line Doesn't End? Please help

Tags: errors

Please help! I don't know how to fix the error.

```
Construct a truth table for each of these compound propositions: \\
a) \[ (P \wedge Q) \rightarrow (P \vee Q) \] \\
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
P & Q & P \ensuremath{\wedge} Q & P \ensuremath{\vee} Q & (P \ensuremath{\wedge} Q) \ensuremath{\rightarrow} (P \ensuremath{\vee} Q) \\ \hline
True & True & True & True & True \\ \hline
True & False & False & True & True \\ \hline
False & True & False & True & True \\ \hline
False & False & False & False & True \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} \\

b) \[ (Q \rightarrow \neg{P}) \leftrightarrow (P \leftrightarrow Q) \] \\

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
P & Q & \ensuremath{\neg{P}} & (Q \ensuremath{\rightarrow} \ensuremath{\neg {P}}) & (P \ensuremath{\leftrightarrow} Q) & (Q \ensuremath{\rightarrow \neg{P}}) \ensuremath{\leftrightarrow} (P \ensuremath{\leftrightarrow} Q) \\ \hline
True & True & False & False & True & False \\ \hline
True & False & False & True & False & False \\ \hline
False & True & True & True & False & False\\ \hline
False & False & True & True & True & True\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} \\
```

! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

Comment: you should remove the `\\ ` after the table but also the ones after `\]` (also why a), b).. by hand rather than use \begin{enumerate}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated inmy initial comment, `table` is a float (it produces no inline text, but is treated separately by LaTeX at a different layer of page typesetting), and so placing `\\` after `\end{table}` is the culprit.  It is as if you placed `\\` in a paragraph by itself...it will produce the same error.

To fix the immediate problem, remove the two instances of `\\` following `\end{table}`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

Construct a truth table for each of these compound propositions: \\
a) \[ (P \wedge Q) \rightarrow (P \vee Q) \] \\
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
P & Q & P \ensuremath{\wedge} Q & P \ensuremath{\vee} Q & (P \ensuremath{\wedge} Q) \ensuremath{\rightarrow} (P \ensuremath{\vee} Q) \\ \hline
True & True & True & True & True \\ \hline
True & False & False & True & True \\ \hline
False & True & False & True & True \\ \hline
False & False & False & False & True \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

b) \[ (Q \rightarrow \neg{P}) \leftrightarrow (P \leftrightarrow Q) \] \\

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
P & Q & \ensuremath{\neg{P}} & (Q \ensuremath{\rightarrow} \ensuremath{\neg {P}}) & (P \ensuremath{\leftrightarrow} Q) & (Q \ensuremath{\rightarrow \neg{P}}) \ensuremath{\leftrightarrow} (P \ensuremath{\leftrightarrow} Q) \\ \hline
True & True & False & False & True & False \\ \hline
True & False & False & True & False & False \\ \hline
False & True & True & True & False & False\\ \hline
False & False & True & True & True & True\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

**However, 
The real question, though, is why do you want to place the `tabular`s in floating `table`s?**

Instead, I would remove the `table` environments, and also set the top row of each table directly in math mode.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
Construct a truth table for each of these compound propositions:

\noindent a) \[ (P \wedge Q) \rightarrow (P \vee Q) \] 
{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
$P$ & $Q$ & $P \wedge Q$ & $P \vee Q$ & $(P \wedge Q) \rightarrow (P \vee Q)$ \\ \hline
True & True & True & True & True \\ \hline
True & False & False & True & True \\ \hline
False & True & False & True & True \\ \hline
False & False & False & False & True \\ \hline
\end{tabular}\par}

\noindent b) \[ (Q \rightarrow \neg{P}) \leftrightarrow (P \leftrightarrow Q) \] 
{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
$P$ & $Q$ & $\neg{P}$ & $(Q \rightarrow \neg {P})$ & $(P \leftrightarrow Q)$ & $(Q \rightarrow \neg{P}) \leftrightarrow (P \leftrightarrow Q)$ \\ \hline
True & True & False & False & True & False \\ \hline
True & False & False & True & False & False \\ \hline
False & True & True & True & False & False\\ \hline
False & False & True & True & True & True\\ \hline
\end{tabular}\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is indeed *no* reason for placing these tables in a `table` environment. By the way, the headers should be in math mode.

Comment: I am a beginner at LaTeX, so my coding is very primitive, please forgive me ;; i have more code besides this in the document so maybe that counteracts your argument but I cannot show my whole code because it is for a class.